# Received a tax refund check after my business' checking account is closed and the entity's dissolved

Tags: taxes, banking, income-tax-refund

I had an LLC and closed the LLC's checking account. Then the LLC was dissolved a few months back. A couple days ago, I found out that my business received a tax refund check two months ago, but I'm just now finding this out. Long story.

I went to deposit it at the bank, but because it is written out to the LLC and not me personally, they said call the state and have them reissue it to you. I'm going to do this on Monday, but I have a question in the meantime.

If my business account was linked to my online banking, which has my personal account there too, and the bank knows I was the sole owner... and everyone agrees I was the only owner... why couldn't they deposit this into my personal account? What is the legality when it comes to depositing a dissolved business' check into its former sole owner's personal account? Especially being a tax refund.

Comment: The bank doesn't know under what circumstances the LLC dissolved.  Perhaps there are creditors entitled to receive payments from the LLC, but not from you.  The bank isn't going to mix your finances with the LLC without express instructions from you, and the mechanism for processing those instructions (the open account) no longer exists.

Comment: This is one reason accounts, and books, are often held open for some time after a business entity shuts down, to allow late transactions to finish processing.